# Can't access $_SESSION after ini_set

Tags: php, session, ini-set

since I have change some settings with ini_set I can't access to the sessions information anymore, but they exist and are correct.
These are the setting:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '../php/config/session');
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'sha512');
ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom');
ini_set('session.entropy_length', '512');
ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', '1');
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', '1');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '1');
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', '0');
session_name("RazorphynSupport");
session_start();
```

The php doesn't throw out any error.
Thanks

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION);` return?

Comment: Do you put all your ini_set on every script ? If you set the save_path on one script and try to get the session value on another script without setting again de save_path. You won't get any PHP error but the session will be empty.

Comment: Yes,I have put those lines on every page(I have also changed the path). var_dump says: array(0){}

Comment: Is it normal that everytime I create a new session file the php create 2 files(one empty and one with information)?

Comment: try to add `ini_set('session.auto_start',0);` and remove all files from `../php/config/session`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem: `ini_set('session.cookie_secure', '1');` the SSL certified wasn't installed in 'the right way' so my server couldn't recognize it and detect the open session